# 3D Shortcut in the bottom instead in the top

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using this code to create 3D Touch shortcut for my app:

```
- (void)configDynamicShortcutItems {
    UIApplicationShortcutIcon *shortcutSearchIcon = [UIApplicationShortcutIcon iconWithType:UIApplicationShortcutIconTypeSearch];
    UIApplicationShortcutIcon *shortcutFavoriteIcon = [UIApplicationShortcutIcon iconWithType:UIApplicationShortcutIconTypeFavorite];

    UIApplicationShortcutItem *shortcutSearch = [[UIApplicationShortcutItem alloc]
                                                 initWithType:@"com.sarangbang.QuickAction.Search"
                                                 localizedTitle:@"Search"
                                                 localizedSubtitle:nil
                                                 icon:shortcutSearchIcon
                                                 userInfo:nil];

    UIApplicationShortcutItem *shortcutFavorite = [[UIApplicationShortcutItem alloc]
                                                 initWithType:@"com.sarangbang.QuickAction.Favorite"
                                                 localizedTitle:@"Favorite"
                                                 localizedSubtitle:nil
                                                 icon:shortcutFavoriteIcon
                                                 userInfo:nil];


    NSArray *items = @[shortcutSearch, shortcutFavorite];

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].shortcutItems = items;
}
```

Ant I noticed that the shortcut is in the bottom when I make a long press on the icon:
[image]

But when I check other apps I see it's on the top:
[image]

Any idea what is the problem? Why the shortcut is in the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Your shortcuts are all dynamic (defined in code). The other apps have static shortcuts (defined in the Info.plist, not in code).

Comment: I try this and is was the same, any idea why?